# Manipulating pandas dataframe - specific

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,11,2],[2,11,3],[1,22,7],[2,22,8],[3,22,9],[1,33,15],[2,33,16],[3,33,17],[4,33,18],[5,33,19]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Leg','Amt'])
print(df)
OUT:
       Date  Leg  Amt
    0     1   11    2
    1     2   11    3
    2     1   22    7
    3     2   22    8
    4     3   22    9
    5     1   33   15
    6     2   33   16
    7     3   33   17
    8     4   33   18
    9     5   33   19
```

I would like to convert it to the format:

```
Date   11  22  33
1      2   7   15
2      3   8   16
3      X   9   17
4      X   X   18
5      X   X   19
```

X = Don't care could be NA/Nan

I want to do some analysis datewise for each Leg, so trying to bring the Legs data date wise.

Many thanks, ahead!

Comment: Try df.pivot(*df)

Comment: That's not a particularly good design.  "11" is not a "type of thing", it is one of the data items. What does that let you do that you couldn't do by querying the table you have?

Comment: @BENY please let me know where can I get a coffee delivered for you ;). Thanks.

Comment: @007 glad I could help ~ BTW happy Friday ~~~